# Insert into table with a MAP data type in Hive

Tags: dictionary, streaming, hive

I am trying to use a hive streaming job to insert data into a table which contains a column with a MAP data type.

I have tried setting up all the delimiters in the table definition and then outputting data from the streaming job in the correct format.

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ','
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I have also tried outputting the data in the exact format that Hive stores maps `({key:value})`.

Here is the error I keep seeing:

```
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 7:23 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different 'table_name': Cannot convert column 2 from string to map<string,string>.
```

Is it possible to do this in Hive?

Comment: any updates about your error?

Answer (score 0):

without your data sample and full table schema,I can't explain the cause of error for you.

Apparently according your ROW FORMAT definition;
the map structure in your data should be(assume size 2 map):

`....\tkey1|value2,key2|value2\t...other columns\n`